# Inverse trigonometric function related problem

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Considering the principal values of the inverse trigonometric function, the sum of all the solution of the  equation ${\cos ^{ - 1}}x - 2{\sin ^{ - 1}}x = {\cos ^{ - 1}}2x$  is equal to ____

My approach is as follow

${\cos ^{ - 1}}x - 2{\sin ^{ - 1}}x = {\cos ^{ - 1}}2x$

It is given that ${\sin ^{ - 1}}x + {\cos ^{ - 1}}x = \frac{\pi }{2} \Rightarrow 2{\sin ^{ - 1}}x + 2{\cos ^{ - 1}}x = \pi $

$ \Rightarrow {\cos ^{ - 1}}x + 2{\cos ^{ - 1}}x - \pi  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}x - 2{\sin ^{ - 1}}x$

$ \Rightarrow 3{\cos ^{ - 1}}x - \pi  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}x - 2{\sin ^{ - 1}}x = {\cos ^{ - 1}}2x \Rightarrow 3{\cos ^{ - 1}}x - {\cos ^{ - 1}}2x = \pi $

$ - 1 \le 2x \le 1$ & $ - \frac{1}{2} \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$

Not able to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! Rewrite as $$3\cos^{-1}(x)=\pi+\cos^{-1}(2x)$$

Now take the cosine on both sides,

$$\cos\left(3\cos^{-1}(x)\right)=\cos\left(\pi+\cos^{-1}(2x)\right)$$

$$\implies4x^3-3x=-2x\implies4x^3=x$$

This has solutions $x=0,\pm\frac12$, all of which belong to the domain. Thus, the sum of all solutions of the given equation is $0$.